# Circular go channels

Tags: go, concurrency

I have two go channels (`ch1` and `ch2`, `ch1` is used as a queue, I send a string to it and a new go routine will process it; many go routines might be processing strings from this queue. Each of these routines will send outputs to the second channel (`ch2`) that will be processed by another routine that might send a new string to the first channel (`ch1`). If no more strings are enqueued in  `ch1` and `ch2` is also empty I want to finish the program.

The problem is that I'm emptying the wait group before the new message is enqueued. How can I do this circular communication between the two channels?

```
ch1 -> ch2 
    <-
```

This is the non working code:

```golang
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

ch1 := make(chan string)
ch2 := make(chan string)



go func() {
  for each := range ch1 {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
      defer wg.Done()
      time.Sleep(100 * time.Microsecond)
      // the other routine in the line marked as #a will
      // add a message to ch1 but by then the waitgroup will be empty and wg.Wait() will stop blocking
      ch2 <- each + "_processed"
    }()
  }
}()

go func() {
  count := 0
  for i := range ch2 {
    if count < 2 {
      // #a
      ch1 <- i
    }
    count++
  }
}()
// start the loop
ch1 <- "A"
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Adrian Updated the body with the question: how to make circular communication between two channels and finish when there are no more messages to process?

Comment: If you have a goroutine for each item put into ch1, then do the `wg.Add` before you add the item to ch1 (2 places in your program). When all processing for all ch1 items are done, your program is done.

Comment: thanks, trying now I was able to make it work doing the `wg.Add` before the line with `ch1 <- "A"` and before adding to `ch2` so that the workgroup won't be emptied before `ch2` tries to add back the message to `ch1`